# Is it possible to specify the type of an array in AS3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

In many languages you can specify that an array is of a certain type. For instance, in Java you could write:

```
String[] arrayOfStrings;
```

However in ActionScript 3 it seems that you can only specify that an object is of type Array, for instance:

```
var myArray:Array;
```

Is there a way to specify what type of object an AS3 array will contain?

Comment: If AS3 is like PHP, and I think it is, there IS no actual constructor for an array.  It's an object that is simply called an array.  This means that each index in the array can be anything.  So, one array can hold [1,"one"] at the same time.

Comment: @durbnpoisn No, AS3 is not like that at all. ;) There is an [`Array` type which extends `Object`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html). You are right that an `Array` can hold any values, but there is also a [`Vector` type which is a typed array](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Vector.<String>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html) to store several objects of the given type in an array. `Vector` is type-safe and is faster than `Array` so in almost all cases (when it's up to you) you should use `Vector` instead of `Array`.

I also recommend reading [this article](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/702) about the various ways to construct a vector. The article is from 2010 (so many Flash Player improvements have been done since then) but much of it still applies and you can download Jackson's test source to run the performance test on the current player.